# runas command plus netsh interface

Tags: windows-7, runas, netsh

I try to use this code to disable wifi interface and enable lan interface when user davide login. The script starts at startup it prompts me for password (twice) but then it fails.. I added pause command to see what happens but I do not know what I am doing wrong..

```
runas /user:davide "netsh interface set interface 'Connessione rete wireless' disabled"
pause
runas /user:davide "netsh interface set interface 'Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)' enabled"
```

My operating system is windows 7 professional 64Bit..

May you help me?

Comment: Try using `\"` instead of `'`

Comment: I edited the script in this way, I don't know if it is right: "netsh interface set interface \"Connessione rete wireless\" but it doesn't work..